# No Mocha version is shown in the package.json when testing with cypress

Tags: repository, mocha.js, cypress, version, package.json

I am using cypress. But as I understand the cypress is built above mocha. So, I want to check what mocha version the project I am working with uses. I am heading to the `package.json` doing the search, but finding no mocha dependencies. Does it mean that mocha is built into cypress? How could I determine the used inside cypress mocha version then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Updated**

As Drew pointed out there are many versions of Mocha used in various packages under the Cypress repository.

I'm not sure that `dependencies` vs `devDependencies` is a solid indicator, since Cypress uses the Mocha library to make a modified version.

Here's a sampling from packages in the Cypress 12.16.0 repo:

- npm/webpack-dev-server: "mocha": "^9.2.2",
- npm/vite-dev-server: "mocha": "^9.2.2",
- graphql: "mocha": "^8.1.3",
- launcher: "mocha": "^8.1.3",
- tooling/electron-mksnapshot: "mocha": "^9.2.0",
- webpack-batteries-included-preprocessor: "mocha": "^8.1.1",
- webpack-preprocessor:  "mocha": "^7.1.0",
- server: "mocha": "7.1.0",
  etc

so it kind of depends on the part of the Cypress suite you are using (Component tester, e2e runner, module api)

The link I would use for e2e testing is the [driver package](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/blob/12823cd59771ebf40b095cc8c49063f5f4109adf/packages/driver/package.json#L69)

> ```js
>   "devDependencies": {
>     ...
>     "mocha": "7.0.1",
> ```

---

Another approach that currently works is querying the global `Cypress` object.

```js
it('log the Mocha version in use', function() { 
  console.log(Cypress.mocha._mocha.version)   // 7.0.1 for Cypress 12.16.0
})
```

where `Cypress.mocha` is the instance object and `Cypress.mocha._mocha` is the class definition (shown in devtools as `Mocha` type).

These properties may be removed at a future time.

Comment: That's listed as devDependency and mochar@v3.5.3 is 6 years old... surely that can't be right

Comment: `driver` package is the correct one, you can tell by inspecting the code behind.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's listed under [`./packages/server/package.json`](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/blob/12823cd59771ebf40b095cc8c49063f5f4109adf/packages/server/package.json#L95)

And tied to `mocha@7.0.1` atm.